# How to combine 4 columns from 2 Access queries into 3 columns of single query?

Tags: sql, union

This question is similar to the one here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846064/sql-union-query-with-extra-field-in-results) however it does differ.

I am trying to combine two different queries into one query. Each query has 2 columns. Here is some sample data.

```
Query #1
Country | Quantity
USA     | 312
Canada  | 513
Mexico  | 258

Query #2
Country | Quanity
USA     | 425
UK      | 394
Mexico  | 489
```

And then the final query needs to look like this...

```
Country | Query#1 | Query #2
USA     | 312     | 425
Canada  | 513     | 0
UK      | 0       | 394
Mexico  | 258     | 489
```

The empty ones can be blank, or 0 it does not matter.

It seems like I need to use a FULL OUTER JOIN, or something to that affect, but Access does not have a FULL OUTER JOIN.

I have tried to use a union query, but I do not understand them well enough to accomplish this. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: He mentions MSAccess in the title, so Query1 and Query2 are probably saved Queries.  In MSAccess world, they work like views...

Comment: Each query is really complex because it is pulling the information from several places. There is another column in each query (#1 &#2) that is vendor. And by placing a criteria line that is what gets the correct numbers. Not sure if that is clear or not....

Answer (score -1):

You want to create a query that joins your other two queries.  In order to get nulls (or zeros) from both Queries, you'll need to have a table and/or a Query that has all the countries.  Then, you can outer join to the other two tables like so (assuming the Country table/query is called Country):

```
SELECT Country.Country, Query1.Quantity, Query2.quantity 
FROM Country
LEFT OUTER JOIN Query1 ON Query1.Country = Country.Country
LEFT OUTER JOIN Query2 ON Country.Country = Query2.Country
```

Comment: If you want blank values, then you'll need to have a table/Query that just lists the Countries, and then you can outer join both Query1 and Query2 to the Countries table so you can get blank values.

Comment: That is close, but it looks like I need an OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. However if I replace INNER with OUTER or FULL or FULL OUTER Access throws an error?

Comment: I don't believe MS Access does full outer joins.  You can do a LEFT OUTER JOIN but that will only get you blank values from 1 of the queries.  Otherwise, you'd have the list of countries and then OUTER JOIN both Query1 and Query2 to the Country table/query.